# oracle to mongodb data migration using kafka

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-kafka

i am trying to migrate data from oracle to mongodb using kafka. I took a sample record set of 10 million with column length of 90 each row is of 5Kb

i am dividing the data into 10 threads but one of the thread is not running every time.... when i check the data i see 1 million records are missing in mongodb.

main class:

```
    int totalRec = countNoOfRecordsToBeProcessed;
    int minRownum =0;
    int maxRownum =0;
    int recInThread=totalRec/10;
    System.out.println("oracle  "+new Date());
    for(int i=minRownum;i<=totalRec;i=i+recInThread+1){ 
          KafkaThread kth = new KafkaThread(i, i+recInThread, conn);
        Thread th = new Thread(kth);
        th.start();
    }
    System.out.println("oracle done+  "+new Date());
```

kafka producer thread class:

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        while(rs.next()){

```
        int total_rows = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {
            obj.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1)
                    .toLowerCase(), rs.getObject(i + 1));
     }
            //System.out.println("object->"+serializedObject);
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("oracle_1",obj.toString()));
            obj= new JSONObject();
        //System.out.println(counter++);
}
```

consumer class:

```
        KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        //subscribe to topic
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));

        MongoClientURI clientURI = new MongoClientURI(mongoURI);
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(clientURI);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(clientURI.getDatabase());
        final MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(clientURI.getCollection());
        while (true) {
            final ConsumerRecords<Long, String> consumerRecords =
                    consumer.poll(10000);

            if (consumerRecords.count()!=0) {
                List<InsertOneModel> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
                consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
//                    System.out.printf("Consumer Record:(%d, %s, %d, %d)\n",
//                            record.key(), record.value(),
//                            record.partition(), record.offset());'

                    String row =null;
                     row = record.value();
                     Document doc=Document.parse(row);
                     InsertOneModel t = new InsertOneModel<>(doc);
                     list1.add(t);
                });
                collection.bulkWrite((List<? extends WriteModel<? extends Document>>) (list1), new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false));
                consumer.commitAsync();
                list1.clear();
            }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you writing code to do this, and not using Kafka Connect?

Comment: i was asked to write a piece of code which ingest the data as fast as possible ... i tried multiple things java multithreading, plsql etc but i found this to be the best in performance

Comment: My advice: use Kafka Connect JDBC connector to pull the data in, and Kafka Connect MongoDB sink to push the data out. Otherwise you are just reinventing the wheel.

Comment: ok thanks will tryout ... any link for more info is highly appreciated !!!

Comment: btw wanted to know like why one of the thread is missed to be consumed ??

Comment: I've posted an answer with some links to Kafka Connect resources in.

Answer (score 3):

My advice: use [Kafka Connect JDBC connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_connector.html) to pull the data in, and a [Kafka Connect MongoDB sink](https://github.com/hpgrahsl/kafka-connect-mongodb) to push the data out. Otherwise you are just reinventing the wheel. Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka.

Getting started with Kafka Connect:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/

Comment: thanks @robin :) will definately try out ... btw is there any performance benchmark on this??? i mean i need to transfer 130Million records from one of the table.. is it worth to proceed with this approach ?

Comment: What's your time window for loading those 130M records? 1 sec? 1 week?

Comment: this is a POC assignment at office.. so the requirement is that the data should be transfered as quick as possible and this is a batch job... not real time streaming

Comment: @user1708054 Can you share your further experience regarding this. It is really interesting to know. Adding further, Although I have worked on Kafka, but never tried the use case that you mentioned and also I cannot comment about the benchmark but transferring 130Million records, should be fine with Kafka.

Comment: @SuhasChikkanna this was nice experience for me to learn kafka and producer API.... although i felt for this purpose kafka connect is easy way.. as i was trying to handle all the scenarios which are already present.

Comment: @user1708054 That's great. But with the above discussions, I thought you used Kafka Connect for your case (instead of producer/consumer API of kafka) and hence, I was interested to know your use case with respect to Kafka Connect. I tried to find some good blogs regarding your use case with respect to Kafka Connect but could not. So was interested to know, if you had found any related blog or source that helped you in your accomplishment.

Comment: @SuhasChikkanna ... if i explore anything on this part will share it here.. thanks :)

Comment: I am exploring a similar requirement, where in read the data from multiple tables in MS-SQL Server and load into Azure Cosmos DB (Using MongoDB API Connector).. My Query is how can I transform the kafka message where in 8 Tables get transformed into 1 JSON Document in Cosmos